# Can't make an API request using fetch or jQuery from sd+

Tags: javascript, jquery, fetch-api

I've tried jQuery and `fetch` and I can't get either of them to work. I tried PowerShell and it works there.

Service desk + has a beta thing that's super cool so I'm doing some testing and trying to get a HTML form to work with the beta before I got out and hook it up to my work system. I also tried writing it myself with fetch or jQuery with no luck so I went to Postman and the request works with postman but then when I grab the code and throw it in vs with live server I get this error:

> GET https://beta.servicedeskplus.com/api/v3/requests/%7B2%7D net::ERR_ABORTED 404

Also don't worry about the API key this is something publicly available to anyone.

Here's my code:

```js
var myHeaders = new Headers();
myHeaders.append("authtoken", "C9BE41C7-F13F-4AB8-9A7B-A16650998909");
myHeaders.append("Cookie", "SDPSESSIONID=B465412CABBBCB2271CDBCA682EEF2A7; 
_zcsr_tmp=f3eddbc3-cbf9-434d-b6f3-19f3c2038556; sdpcsrfcookie=f3eddbc3-cbf9-434d-b6f3- 
19f3c2038556");

var requestOptions = {
  method: 'GET',
  headers: myHeaders,
  redirect: 'follow',
  mode: "no-cors"
};

fetch("https://beta.servicedeskplus.com/api/v3/requests/{2}", requestOptions)
  .then(response => response.text())
  .then(result => console.log(result))
  .catch(error => console.log('error', error));
```

Comment: I have absolutely no idea what your question is trying to explain, or what the goal is. However the general advice in this situation is to open devtools and debug the request that gets sent. You will be able to see the status code and response text.

Comment: Also, if that line break really is in the middle of your string literal, then that's a syntax error.

Comment: `mode: "no-cors"` - why? Are you aware what restrictions that implies? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Request/mode#value - _"Prevents the method from being anything other than HEAD, GET or POST, and the headers from being anything other than simple headers."_ - neither `authtoken` nor `Cookie` are "simple headers." And, _"In addition, JavaScript may not access any properties of the resulting Response."_ - so your `.then(response => response.text())` would not make sense either.

Comment: I looked at the network tab and it shows code 400 and response Failed to load response data: no data found for resource with given identifier. My question is why isn't my GET request working when using Fetch or Jquery

Comment: And you are confident the URL is supposed to contain {2}?